# How to set short side of video to a constant?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have videos with different edges. For example `1920x1080, 1080x1920, 720x720`.

I want to scale them down and set shortest side to 300 and keep aspect ratio with ffmpeg.

Result should be:
`533x300,300x533, 300x300`

What should I type to ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale filter syntax would be

```
scale=w='if(lte(iw,ih),300,-1)':h='if(lte(iw,ih),-1,300)'
```